# Maximum (limit) upload file size for apache and gunicorn

Tags: django, apache, post, upload, gunicorn

How to setup maximum upload file size or size of request body in apache or gunicorn?

Like "post_max_size" and "upload_max_filesize" but for gunicorn and django.

Comment: Do you want to limit the uploads at the webserver or at the application?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use this param?

```
<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/uploads">
    LimitRequestBody 102400
</Directory>
```